# Calculating time differences in minutes (PHP)

Tags: php, date, timer

I want to set a timer and calculate how long it takes to do a task.

So I have the following PHP code set up just to test:

```
$firstDate = date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
sleep(80);
$secondDate = date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
$diffDates = (strtotime($secondDate) - strtotime($firstDate));

echo "Difference in dates is:" . $diffDates . "\n";
```

When I run it though it gives me the following output:

```
    Difference in dates is:-40
```

What I'm wondering is, why does it give me -40, and how can I set it up so that I can just do a simple calculation of ending date - starting date in minutes.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just tested your code with sleep(5), I have 5 as result. You have only this code ?

Comment: You are using `date` to make a time string to then use `strtotime()` to convert back to an integer.  You can save yourself some trouble with: `$firstDate = time();sleep(80);$secondDate=time();$diff=$secondDate-$firstDate;`

Comment: Doesn't explain the result of -40 though, strange I got 20 when it should have been 80.

Comment: oh, I didn't see it at first, now it makes total sense.  See my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are giving the wrong date format for time. Which should be `h:i:s` not `h:m:s`

So your date will be: `date('Y-m-d h:i:s')`

```
$firstDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
sleep(80);
$secondDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$diffDates = (strtotime($secondDate) - strtotime($firstDate));

echo "Difference in dates is:" . $diffDates . "\n";
```

Then output will be: `Difference in dates is:80`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have your time format string wrong:

`$firstDate = date('Y-m-d h:m:s');`

The second `m`, which should be `i` for 'minutes', is actually 'month' again, so it was `07`

This will fix it:

`date('Y-m-d h:i:s')`

It's also worth noting that if you use this format you should add `a` to the end to designate `am` or `pm`, or use `H` in place of `h` for a 24 hour format.

This could cause issues. For example where I am right now it is 3:17 pm, so when I do this:

```
echo time();
echo "<br>";
echo strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s'));
```

my output is:

```
1501010231
1500967031
```

But using `date('Y-m-d h:i:s a')` or `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` would give the intended result of both values being identical.

Answer (score 0):

$firstDate = new \DateTime();

sleep(80);

$secondDate = new \DateTime();

$interval = $firstDate->diff($secondDate);

echo "Difference in dates is:" . $interval->s . "\n";

> > Result: Difference in dates is:80